# Return time interval as a double in C#

Tags: c#, time, group-by

I am new to this forum and C# programming.Working on this project where I have to return time interval as a double  after if control statement finished. Code snippet is below. Please tell me what I am doing wrong. It's not returning `d`;

```
public double GetInterval()
{
    double d;
    DateTime now = new DateTime();

    if (cb5Min.Checked)
    {
        d = ((60 - now.Second) * 1000 - now.Millisecond);            
    }
    else if (cb15Min.Checked)
    {
        d= ((900 - now.Second) * 1000 - now.Millisecond);
    }

    return d;
}
```

Comment: What happens if neither of the tests is true? What does the compiler's error message say? Should we have to guess information that you already have?

Comment: You are returning a possibly unassigned local variable; the code probably doesn't compile as is.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at `TimeSpan` Structure and example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Not all of your paths will update d.
If cb5Min.checked is false and cb15Min.checked is false then the code will return the unitnitialised value of d.